# tocando arquivos mp3 no Python

Tags: python, áudio, documentação

Estava fazendo exercícios do Curso em Vídeo sobre Python e estagnei no Desafio 21, cujo objetivo é fazer um programa que toque um arquivo mp3. Contudo, já tentei da forma que me foi mostrada no vídeo e não deu certo, já tentei das formas que vi nos comentários e também não deu certo por estarem ou obsoletos ou em manutenção. Gostaria de saber sobre algum código atual que exerça a sua função efetivamente. Agradeço desde já a atenção. :)

Segue a fio meus códigos que havia tentado anteriormente:

**Através do Pygame do ano do vídeo (2017)**

```
import pygame
pygame.mixer.init()
pygame.init()
pygame.mixer.music.load('McPoze.mp3')
pygame.music.play()
pygame.event.wait()
```

-Erro: *pygame.error: Couldn't open 'McPoze.mp3'*

**Por ajuda dos comentários**

```
import pygame
pygame.mixer.init()
pygame.mixer.music.load('McPoze.mp3')
pygame.mixer.music.play()
input()
pygame.event.wait()
```

-Erro: *pygame.error: Couldn't open 'McPoze.mp3'*

```
import playsound
playsound.playsound('McPoze.mp3')
```

-Erro: *UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe3 in position 24: invalid continuation byte*

```
import webbrowser
webbrowser.open('McPoze.mp3')
```

-Erro: abre uma aba no Internet Explorer sem relação com o mp3

Comment: Amigo isso acontece porque o seu Python está atualizado e a biblioteca não. Recomendo utilizar o Python3.6 para usar a biblioteca do Pygame.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O código que você usou com o pygame deveria funcionar.

O seu erro pode não ser relacionado ao pygame. O arquivo `McPoze.mp3` existe e está na mesma pasta onde interpretador foi aberto? Você pode  verificar o diretório atual do interpretador python com

```
import os
print(os.getcwd())
```

Se a pasta não for a mesma onde está o arquivo `McPoze.mp3` então basta colocar o caminho completo do arquivo ao invés de apenas o nome.

Existem também algumas outras bibliotecas que você poderia tentar como alternativa para tocar áudio no python. [Esse link](https://pythonbasics.org/python-play-sound/) lista algumas opções. Testei rapidamente as duas primeiras (`playsound` e `pydub` instalados usando pip) e funcionaram bem. Reproduzo o exemplo das duas que testei abaixo.

```py
from playsound import playsound
playsound('audio.mp3')
```

O comando `playsound` bloqueia enquanto o áudio toca e Ctrl+C não para imediatamente.

```py
from pydub import AudioSegment
from pydub.playback import play

song = AudioSegment.from_mp3("sound.wav")
play(song)
```

O `pydub` é mais interassante. Ele mostra o progresso do áudio e Ctrl+C oara imediatamente de maneira limpa.

Comment: A função _playsound_ continua dando o mesmo erro que eu havia posto acima e em relação ao _pydub_ que você objetificou seguidamente, não entendi como usá-la mesmo entrando no site atenuado. :(

Comment: Talvez porque que faltou importar `AudioSegment`. Eu editei a resposta e adicionei o import.

Comment: O seu problema também pode ser apenas pelo fato de a pasta atual do interpretador python não ser a mesma onde está o arquivo mp3. Eu editei a resposta sobre como checar se esse é o caso.

Comment: O problema era com o local de arquivo mesmo, muito obrigado amigo! consegui resolver com o módulo de achar o diretório! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
import pygame

pygame.init()
pygame.mixer.music.load('favela.mp3')
pygame.mixer.music.play()
pygame.event.wait()
input()
```

Comment: Recomendo inserir explicações sobre o que foi feito em sua resposta de forma a não apenas "resolver" o problema do autor da pergunta, mas esclarecer o que foi feito e como resultou na resolução do problema reportado.

Answer (score -1):

Parece que a ferramenta foi "descontinuada", porém eu consegui usar fazendo o seguinte. Detalhe: estou usando o PyCharm 2020 então vou dizer como fiz por ele ok.
Vai em File, settings, python interpreter, clica duas vezes sobre o pip, daí na barra de pesquisa escreva playsound, na tela do lado direito tem que aparecer  algo sobre que essa biblioteca está disponível pelo github de Taylor Marks. No canto inferior esquerdo marque a caixinha escrito: Install to user's site packages directory, depois só clicar no botão abaixo Install Package. Só aguardar a instalação e depois manda roda o código. O meu deu boa!
[image: como fazer]

Answer (score -1):

Acabei de ter o mesmo problema e, analisando a biblioteca `pygame`, percebi que a função `music` foi substituìda por `mixer_music`. Com esse última, tudo funciona OK.

Meu exemplo:

```
import pygame

pygame.mixer.init()
pygame.init()
pygame.mixer.music.load('alok_ringtone.mp3')
pygame.mixer_music.play()
pygame.event.wait()
```

Espero ter ajudado.

Answer (score -1):

```
import pygame
import os
pygame.init()
if os.path.exists('musica.mp3'):
  pygame.mixer.music.load('musica.mp3')
  pygame.mixer.music.play()
  pygame.mixer.music.set_volume(1)

  clock = pygame.time.Clock()
  clock.tick(10)

  while pygame.mixer.music.get_busy():
     pygame.event.poll()
     clock.tick(10)
else:
  print('O arquivo musica.mp3 não está no diretório do script Python')
```